# WriteListener (servlet 3.1) semantics

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-3.1

Let's say I'm writing chunks of data to an `HttpServletResponse`. So my method receives an array of bytes, I write it to `response.getOutputStream()`, and then I release the thread. When I receive another chunk of data, my method will be awaken, and it will write to `getOutputStream()` again. In the end, I call to `AsyncContext.complete()`.

Now, the `WriteListener.onWritePossible()` spec says:

> this method will be invoked by the container the first time when it is
>   possible to write data. The container will subsequently invoke the
>   onWritePossible method if and only if isReady method on
>   ServletOutputStream, described below, returns false.

It seems that when the container calls this method, I already need to have my response buffered somewhere, because `onWritePossible()` may never be called again. So, for the previous example, I need to write all chunks of data I receive in a buffer (a byte array, or maybe a temporary file if the buffer is big enough), and if `onWritePossible()` is called before my response is complete, what should I do? Block the thread until I have all my response data?

Answer (score 1):

Check code in following link. May not be the exact solution but it's idea can be a solution for your case:
[Servlet 3.1 Async IO Echo](https://github.com/jetty-project/jetty-bench/blob/master/bench-9-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/benchmark/Servlet31AsyncIOEchoBenchmark.java)

Answer (score 0):

hmm.. Maintaining a buffer seems to be the way

```
    public void onWritePossible() throws IOException {
       doWrite();  
    }

    // this is some callback where you received next chunk of data
    public void onMoreDataReceived(byte[] data) {
      putDataToBuffer(data);
      doWrite();
    }

    // this method is non-blocking
    private void synchronized doWrite() throws IOException {
       while (_servletOutputStream.isReady() && hasMoreDataInBuffer()) {
         _servletOutputStream.write(getMoreBytesFromBuffer());
       }
    }
```